# Is the function $|V_{\alpha}|$ normal?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is the function $|V_{\alpha}|$, that is, the function that assigns to $\alpha$ the cardinality of $V_{\alpha}$, a normal function?
I think it is but I am not really sure, please help.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For infinite ordinals, $|V_\alpha| = \beth_\alpha$, where the beth function is defined by

$\beth_0 = \aleph_0$

$\beth_{\alpha + 1} = 2^{\beth_\alpha}$

If $\beta$ is a limit ordinal, then $\beth_{\beta} = \sup \{\beth_\alpha : \alpha < \beta\}$.

It is clear that the $\beth$ function is normal (increasing and continuous).

Comment: Actually, since the usual definition of the beth function starts at $0$, $|V_\alpha| = \beth_{\omega + \alpha}$.